# How to call a method when disposing

Tags: rx-swift

I have this piece of code in RxSwift that wraps UDPBroadcastConnection (https://github.com/gunterhager/UDPBroadcastConnection)
My question is, what do I have to do to call closeConnection() when the observable is disposed?

```
struct UDPBroadcastResponse {
    let ip: String
    let port: Int
    let message: [UInt8]
}

final class RxBroadcaster: UDPBroadcastConnection {
    let response = PublishSubject<UDPBroadcastResponse>()
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
}

extension RxBroadcaster: ReactiveCompatible {}

extension Reactive where Base: RxBroadcaster {
    func send(message: String) -> Observable<UDPBroadcastResponse> {
        DDLogVerbose("Sending UDP broadcast message: \(message)")
        self.base.sendBroadcast(message)
        return self.base.response
    }
}

extension RxBroadcaster {
    convenience init(port: UInt16) {
        let rely = ReplaySubject<UDPBroadcastResponse>.createUnbounded()
        self.init(port: port) { ip, port, message in
            let response = UDPBroadcastResponse(ip: ip, port: port, message: message)
            // DDLogVerbose("Receiving UDP message: IP: \(response.ip). Port: \(response.port). Message: \(response.message.map{ String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined())")
            DDLogVerbose("Receiving UDP message: IP: \(response.ip). Port: \(response.port)")
            rely.onNext(response)
        }
        rely.bind(to: self.response).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Here I see an example: http://adamborek.com/practical-introduction-rxswift/
But I am not sure about the lifecycle of the objects involved.
Can you help me?
Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `do` operator to hook into lifecycle events from a subscription and perform side effects. You can call `do` at any point in an Observable chain before you subscribe or bind. Example:

```
rely.do(onDispose: {
    // called as your subscription is being disposed
}).bind(to: self.response).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more inclined to implement the RxBroadcaster like this:

```
final class RxBroadcaster {
    let response: Observable<UDPBroadcastResponse>

    init(port: UInt16) {
        let _response = PublishSubject<UDPBroadcastResponse>()
        let _connection = UDPBroadcastConnection(port: port, handler: { ipAddress, port, response in
            _response.onNext(UDPBroadcastResponse(ip: ipAddress, port: port, message: response))
        })

        response = _response.asObservable()
        completion = _response.asObserver()
        connection = _connection
    }

    deinit {
        connection.closeConnection()
        completion.onCompleted()
    }

    private let connection: UDPBroadcastConnection
    private let completion: AnyObserver<UDPBroadcastResponse>
}

extension RxBroadcaster: ObserverType {
    public func on(_ event: RxSwift.Event<Data>) {
        guard case let .next(data) = event else { return }
        connection.sendBroadcast(data)
    }
}
```

Now you can send data by just binding to the RxBroadcaster `myData.bind(to: myBroadcaster)` and receive data by subscribing to the broadcaster's response. The connection would naturally close when the Broadcaster goes out of scope.

It feels a bit odd to me to do a call/response operator like you did. The point of a UDP socket is that you will get messages independent of the ones you sent.